# Qu'est-ce qui est écrit dans ce dessin ?

Tags: poésie

Bonjour,

J'ai trouvé ce dessin de Paul Verlaine. Savez-vous ce qui est écrit ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Faculté des lettres de Nancy
> Secrétariat
> Nancy 10 novembre 76
> Mossieu,
> Vous appelé c'matin
> Vous pas là
> Vous p'tit muffe  (muffle)
> Vous rasé pour c'te fois
> La secrétaire
> P. Godefroy

Comment: Graphiquement ça ressemble à _Mossieu_, et ça tombe bien le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monsieur) donne [Verlaine](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k202914k/f30.item) quand il en parle...

Comment: Oui, *Mossieu*, j'ai lu trop vite !

Comment: L'abbréviation de novembre en *9bre* n'était pas évidente.

Comment: C'est vrai. On trouve aussi le plus cryptique IXbre...